# как выровнять текст с помощью flexbox?

Tags: frontend, flexbox, codepen

Я решил сделать боковое меню, и применил в нем flexbox, но не могу выровнять текст по центру.

https://codepen.io/ArtaDoxoff/pen/zYmbrMx

`код по ссылке`

Comment: Код должен быть не "по ссылке", а в самом вопросе.